# Prevent internet explorer from scrolling on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Open this fiddle in internet explorer (11): https://jsfiddle.net/kaljak/yw7Lc1aw/1/

Onload the

-Tag is focused and IE slightly scrolls the element so that the table-border is not visible anymore...

```
document.querySelector("P").focus();
```

```js
document.querySelector("P").focus();
```

```css
TABLE {
  border-left: 20px solid blue;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
p {
  width: 1000px;
}
DIV {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p tabindex="0">Test</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I prevent this (no scrolling)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple do like this:

```
   document.querySelector("P").focus();
   document.querySelector("div").scrollTop = 0;
   document.querySelector("div").scrollLeft = 0;
```

Comment: Right, but isn't there any way to prevent IE from doing it and not correcting it later?

Comment: When you focus element it scrolling by default, the only way to use javascript to scroll back

Answer (score 0):

The div element is the one being scrolled:

[image: devtools]

You could use something like

`document.getElementById('t').scrollLeft = 0;`

assuming that you have tagged the wrapping div with `id='t'`

Comment: Right, but isn't there any way to prevent IE from doing it and not correcting it later?